# Scattering from a potential, matrix elements of momentum eigenstates, and the Fourier transform

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential, scattering, fourier-transform, matrix-elements

[image: Homework question]

I am working on my last quantum homework and don't know where to begin with part (i) in this question 4.  Do I need to use a product rule in the FT and use convolution?  Not sure how to go about the FT in bra-ket notation.  I think if I get help with the first question I'll be able to do the rest.  If there are any good examples out there I'd be interested in seeing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your problem? How do you pass from a certain vector |Q> expressed according to some base of vectors   {|$B_i$>} to the same vector |Q> expressed according to another base of vectors {|$C_j$>}?

Let's see it together. Take for example

(1) |Q> = $∑_i$ $a_i$ |$B_i$>,

where $a_i$ are the amplitudes. For passing to the new base you project |Q> on each new vector, and get by reorganizing the product,

(2)  = $∑_i$ $a_i$ <$C_j$|$B_i$>,

So, the vector |Q> in the new base is

(3) |Q> = $∑_j$|$C_j$> $∑_i$ $a_i$ <$C_j$|$B_i$>,,

This is what you do with the function v(k). It is similar to the vector |Q> i.e. instead of ($a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, ...), we should have (v($k_1$), v($k_2$), v($k_3$), ...). But k is CONTINUOUS, not discrete, and so is r in whose representation we want to pass.
Now, for us is important the relation (2). The matrix element <$C_j$|$B_i$> is the expression exp(ikr), and the summation over i becomes in your case is an integral over k.

Similarly with v(k').

Are the things clear?

You don't need convolution here, v(k) and v(k') are expressed in DIFFERENT variables, k and k'. You look when do you need convolution, it is when you have a product of two functions of the same variable.

Good luck !